# std::conditional compiles in Godbolt using msvc but not in VS2019

Tags: c++, templates

I have this code:

```
#include<type_traits>

enum class DataFormat : int8_t
{
    cDouble = 0,
    cFloat  = 1,
    cChar   = 2,
    cBool   = 3
};

class MatrixBase
{
protected:
    MatrixBase(DataFormat const aDataFormat) : _dataFormat(aDataFormat) {}

public:
    DataFormat getFormat() const { return _dataFormat; }

private:
    DataFormat _dataFormat;
};

template<typename tType>
class Matrix final : public MatrixBase
{
private:
    struct DataFormatBool { static constexpr DataFormat _csValue = DataFormat::cBool; };
    struct DataFormatFloat { static constexpr DataFormat _csValue = DataFormat::cFloat; };
    struct DataFormatDouble { static constexpr DataFormat _csValue = DataFormat::cDouble; };
    using ActualDataFormat = typename std::conditional<std::is_same<tType, bool>::value, DataFormatBool,
        std::conditional < std::is_same<tType, float>::value, DataFormatFloat, DataFormatDouble>>::type;
    static_assert(std::is_same<tType, bool>::value || std::is_same<tType, float>::value || std::is_same<tType, double>::value, "Matrix supports only bool, float or double.");

public:
    Matrix()
        : MatrixBase(ActualDataFormat::_csValue)
        
    {  }
};

DataFormat rrr() {
    Matrix<bool> m;
    return m.getFormat();
}
```

It compiles under [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/KEEdW9bEa) but not under VS2019. (There it is larger.) The error is

> model-stl\include\Matrix.h(46,52): error C2039: '_csValue': is not a member of 'std::conditional<false, Matrix::DataFormatFloat, Matrix::DataFormatDouble>'

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Just from a cursory glance, it seems as if there should maybe be an extra ::type after the last std::conditional, like this "DataFormatDouble>::type>::type;".

Comment: First I tried so but fails to compile even in Godbolt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing `rrr`'s declaration to

```
Matrix<float> m;
```

results in a compilation failure on all compilers:

Extraction of the resulting type from the inner `std::conditional` is missing. This should be:

```
using ActualDataFormat =
    typename std::conditional<std::is_same<tType, bool>::value,
                  DataFormatBool,
                  typename std::conditional<
                      std::is_same<tType, float>::value,
                      DataFormatFloat,
                      DataFormatDouble>::type
                  >::type;
```

Comment: Thank you! The second typename was missing.